# Ionic 3 - Downloading and extracting starter 3 failed

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I was trying to start an angular 5 project with the starter as a tutorial in my windows system. But it is showing error as

Downloading and extracting tutorial starter - failed

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.84.225.246:443

And I am working on a proxy.

Please help to solve this.

Comment: It is clearly a network issue. can you show which command you are trying to  run

Comment: Thanks Anand. I was trying to run > ionic start myApp tutorial

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html#using-a-proxy this will help

Comment: But i don't have administrator privilege to set path. What should i do.

Comment: This is difficult to get done then. Ask your network admin to open port for installation or try to connect to some other network which has no proxy settings. Download your setup get it running and then switch back to actual network

Comment: Thanks Anand. Let me try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the workaround:
1) Manually download the project from Git Repo: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base. 
2) Do npm install inside "**ionic2-app-base**" (rename from master). It will install the "**ionic2-starter-tutorial**". Copy the content "src" & "www" from within **ionic2-starter-tutorial** and replace it in "**ionic2-app-base**". 
3) Do *ionic serve*.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue when I start to install the official demo, and I solved this problem when I roll back npm to npm@5.6, wired but it works. Or you could add --verbose to show the details when processing.